Hypothesis testing on total surveys
How should one think about hypothesis-testing ratio scale variables that do not have a distribution resembling a normal/t-distribution, when the data comes from a total survey?
Some background:
I have data from a total survey of youth health. All pupils of certain ages living in the county are invited to respond (but of course we have non-responders, about 30 %).
There are new kinds of nicotine products on the market, and now we want to investigate if there are any differences between youth who use these new products, and those who use the traditional kinds. The null hypothesis being there is no difference, and the alternative two-sided (for continuous variables).
Our ratio scale variables are not normally distributed. BMI for example is probably log-normal, another looks more exponential. My first instinct was to rely on the central limit theorem and run t-tests – but then again I do not have a sample of the population – everyone was invited.
Maybe there shouldn’t even be any hypothesis tests when the population hasn’t been sampled, and I should just report the differences that can be observed.

With 30% non+responders maybe thinking about how to traet that is your main problem. Do you have any information at all about the non+responders?

I think that your intuition about not doing hypothesis tests when you do not have a sample from a population is right. Apart from the non-responders you have responses from everyone in the relevant population and so there is no need to extrapolate from those data. Report confidence intervals rather than do tests. (Your sample size is probably large enough to rely on the central limit theorem, but there are methods for generating intervals from proportions that do not assume normal.)

@kjetilbhalvorsen sadly not much. We reach the population through schools, so the only information we have is the total number of pupils at the time of the survey. (Quite different from our corresponding adult survey where we have a lot of registry information and are abel to calculate design weigths calibrated with regards to the non-responders)

@MichaelLew Thank you, great advice! After writing this question I thougth about it some more. Maybe a related question could have been: is it even a thing to test if there has been a true change in expected value of any other distribution than normal or students-t? For example if you know that your data is poissondistributed do you have to go "through" CLT and z-/t-test or is there a corresponding equation for the poissondistribution? We did not use anything as such on the bachelors level that I studied, but then again there is so much more to learn.

Tests exist for some other parametric distributions, and there are also lots of non-parametric tests that care little or not at all about the population distribution.
